# Bash Script output is always 'ps' when piping to grep from ps regardless of PID results

Tags: linux, bash, grep

given an array of pids and the code:

```
    for i in ${listedPids[@]}
    do
        runningCheck="ps -u $USER | grep $i"
        grepRes=(${runningCheck})
        if [[ -n $grepRes ]]
        then
        echo $grepRes
        echo $runningCheck
            ... code not related to the issue
        fi
    done
```

Regardless if those pids are active or not; I keep getting 'ps' from echo $grepRes while the output of echo $runningCheck shows up with the correct user name and pid. What am I missing?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: You cannot put complex commands in variables. Especially not those with pipelines. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: `grepRes=(${runningCheck})` assigns a string as elements of an array into `grepRes`. If you print `${grepRes[@]}` you'll see it is the whole `${runningCheck}`. Perhaps you meant `grepRes=$(${runningCheck})`?

Comment: In addition, you cannot include pipes `|` and redirections `<`, `>` to the variable then attempt to run. Shell will think these are command parameters. An ugly way would be `grepRes=$(eval ${runningCheck})` but I won't recommend it.

Comment: When you have `pid`s, don't use `ps -u $USER | grep pid`. You can simplify it with `ps --no-heading -p pid`.

Comment: Why are you not using `pgrep`?

Comment: OP has a list of pids. None of the grep family, including pgrep is necessary. `ps --no-heading -p $i` will yield the result he needed.

Comment: Thanks  alvits, I'm new to Bash and the bracket syntax is a bit confusing. I didn't realize I turned the variable into an array. I ended up using runningCheck="$(pgrep -u $USER commandName)"

Comment: Also, not sure what the StackOverflow expected conduct is when someone answers your question as a comment. Do I answer this thread or wait for  alvits to post as an answer?

Comment: Generally, etiquette is to suggest that @alvits make their comment an answer, and then to do it yourself if they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alvits and l0b0 pointed out, I made a few syntax errors: `grepRes=(${runningCheck})` when I just wanted to execute that line and not turn it to a list, and the fact pipes and redirects don't work in variables. In the end pgrep did the job as I just needed to continue looping till all the background processes ended.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
"ps -u $USER | grep $i"
```

by

```
$(ps -u $USER | grep $i)
```

---

> Command Substitution: Bash performs the expansion by executing your command and replacing the command substitution with the standard  output  of  the
>          command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your script and here's what it should look like.

```
for i in "${listedPids[@]}"
    do
        grepRes=$(ps --no-heading -p $i)
        if [[ -n "$grepRes" ]]
        then
        echo "$grepRes"
            ... code not related to the issue
        fi
    done
```

An even shorter code could be written using `while` loop.

```
ps --noheading -p "${listedPids[@]}" | while read grepRes
    do
        echo "$grepRes"
            ... code not related to the issue
    done
```

Comment: `for i in "${listedPids[@]}"`, rather, if it's really an array. Without the quotes, you're expanding the array with the first character of IFS between each entry, and then splitting it again. Sure, with a default IFS value and only numeric array contents that should have no effect, but why ask the shell to do all the extra work?

Comment: Also, putting the check command in a scalar array and expanding it into a command to run is evil (and will break very, very badly in any use case even slightly more complex than this one). See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Also, `echo $foo` (as opposed to `echo "$foo"`) is an antipattern. See entry #14 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thanks for nit-picking, it helps in making codes better. I'll add those even though I don't believe that grepRes will ever have values that will need protection from word splitting. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try eval.

```
runningCheck1="ps -u $USER"
runningCheck2=" | grep $i"
echo $runningCheck1$runningCheck
eval $runningCheck1$runningCheck2
```

Comment: No. `eval` is almost **never** the right solution. And certainly not for this which is a problem caused by trying to use a string where one isn't appropriate.